# A straight indent in a UV Sphere

Tags: mesh

i would just like some help making an indent in a UV Sphere.
I've contacted the person who made the YouTube video but got no response.
An image will be below showing what it looks like. C:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a UVSphere and subdivide it. Find "the equator" and select two equidistant edge loops. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > Select Loop Inner Region. In face mode Extrude-scale, with <kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, the selection by a value between 0 and 1, e.g 0.8. Remove doubles. Bevel edges. Done.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

1. Select the edge loop in center and add an [*edge crease*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/edge_data.html#edge-crease) with
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> and set the crease to `1`
2. [*Bevel*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bevel.html#bevel-edges) the edge with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>
3. [*Inset*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/inset_faces.html?#inset-faces) the new faces with <kbd>I</kbd> followed by
   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to use *depth* (intrude)
4. Add *[Subdivision Surface Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html#subdivision-surface-modifier)* and [*shade smooth*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/shading.html?#shade-smooth)

[image]

Comment: .. a nice hole of 'Blender Golf'  :D  Which keystroke display is that?

Comment: @RobinBetts it’s screencast keys, it was finally updated so works with current builds now.